# Show/hide divs by select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't this work? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm certain that jQuery is working on the WordPress page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#rejestracja-1").bind('change', function(event) {
           var info= jQuery("#abc-24").val();
            if(info=="czynny")
             {
             jQuery(".udzialfull").show();
             }
           elseif(info=="bierny")
             {
               jQuery(".udzialfull").hide();
              }
});
</script>




<form id="rejestracja-1"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Rodzaj udziału 
<select id="abc-24">
<option value="czynny" selected='selected'>czynny</option>
<option value="bierny">bierny</option>
</select>

<fieldset class="udzialfull">
szczegoly
</fieldset>
```

Comment: try placing your javascript code at bottom(just above `</body>` tag

Comment: hmm.. it is above,

Comment: I mean `after all html code`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear. Please add any error messages you're getting on the javascript console of your browser and _describe exactly_ what should happen. Have you included `jquery` in  your html file? Does it load properly? Try the [document.ready mechansim](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to set up you event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.

You're writing *elseif* instead of `else if`.

```js
jQuery("#rejestracja-1").bind('change', function(event) {
  var info = jQuery("#abc-24").val();
  if (info == "czynny") {
    jQuery(".udzialfull").show();
  }
  else if(info == "bierny") {
    jQuery(".udzialfull").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="rejestracja-1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Rodzaj udziału
  <select id="abc-24">
    <option value="czynny" selected='selected'>czynny</option>
    <option value="bierny">bierny</option>
  </select>
  <fieldset class="udzialfull">
    szczegoly
  </fieldset>
</form>
```